# How to copy content from a zip to an Android directory?

Tags: java, android, zip

**Hello everyone.**

*Ask this question so that they could give me a hand and guide me on my way.*

### My problem

*I want to be able to unzip a zip into a folder or directory on the SD card, but my code has not reached the target. Its error is that it does not decompress or copy any of the files in the destination directory. The zip is located in the resources resource folder.*

### My code

```
 private boolean copyFile1(String filename1, String outPath1) {
AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 4;
InputStream in;
OutputStream out;
try {
    in = assetManager.open(filename1);
    String newFileName = outPath1;

    ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(in);
    ZipEntry zEntry = null;
    while ((zEntry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {


        if (zEntry.isDirectory()) {

        } else {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(outPath1));
            BufferedOutputStream bufout = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = zipStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                bufout.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }

            zipStream.closeEntry();
            bufout.close();
            fout.close();
        }
    }
    zipStream.close();
    Log.d("Unzip", "Unzipping complete. path :  " );

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
}
return true;
 }
```

**If they realize where I failed in my code or I know otherwise. Please let me know. Thank you**

Comment: Let's start with this....Can you actually create or copy a file to the SD Card? Have you set permissions to do so? How are you accessing the SD Card? [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464162/how-to-copy-raw-files-into-sd-card) may assist you.

Comment: I do not want to copy or decompress the files in the SD but in the SDcard.Thanks

Comment: I realize that Abraham, this is not what I'm asking. What I am asking is: Can you actually copy a file (any file) to your SD Card? You may not have set permission to do so.

Comment: If I can copy a file. Thank you